# ssh not connecting to vm on vagrant bluemix vm

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use the [vagrant openstack provider](https://github.com/ggiamarchi/vagrant-openstack-provider) to automate my VM setup on Bluemix.  My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
require 'vagrant-openstack-provider'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  config.vm.box       = 'openstack'
  config.ssh.username = 'ibmcloud'

  config.vm.provider :openstack do |os|
    os.openstack_auth_url = 'https://keystone2.open.ibmcloud.com/v2.0/tokens'
    os.username           = '*****'
    os.password           = '*****'
    os.tenant_name        = '*****'
    os.flavor             = '4x8x100'
    os.image              = 'Ubuntu 14.04'
    os.floating_ip_pool   = 'Public-Network'
  end
end
```

An instance gets initiated, but I cannot ssh into it.  Does anything look suspect in my configuration file?

```
...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ************* port 22: Connection refused
==> default: Timeout!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout was because the server took a *very* long time to initialise.  Trying again after about 10 mins, I was able to ssh into the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the time taken is mostly dependent from vagrant vm building activity.
Moreover you have to consider that normally a VM on Bluemix needs 30 seconds more after boot completing to become available for incoming connections